# GridView Format Issue

Tags: c#

I'm working with some code here in a C# grid view and I have it to flag a different color based on a value. I also want to make it easier to read by changing the forecolor of the red backcolor. Might be a stupid question but how can I achieve this in the code where it will flag the backcolor red and the forecolor white? I have tried it a few ways but have been unsuccessful here. It works fine with either or but I want to use both here.

```
protected void grd_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        System.Data.DataRow row = ((System.Data.DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
        if (row["Qty To Sell"].ToString() == "1")
            e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightSalmon;
        else if (row["Qty To Sell"].ToString() == "3")
            e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightSalmon;
        else if (row["Qty To Sell"].ToString() == "2")
            e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightSalmon;
        else if (row["Qty To Sell"].ToString() == "0")
            e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

Comment: If this was WPF and XAML it'd sound like the perfect case for [DataTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger.aspx)

Comment: This can be done using a StyleTrigger or even a Converter as well. If I have some time, I'll try and post a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the label properties to do this.

define your number params:

```
int two = 2;
int four = 4;
```

find your label:

```
Label my_label = (Label)row.FindControl("your_label");
```

convert that label value to an integer :

```
int lbl_value = Convert.ToInt32(my_label.Text);
```

Then change the label properties in your if statement :

```
if ( lbl_value == two)
    { 
      my_label.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White; 
      my_label.Forecolor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;  
     }
```

And so on. I like to just change the label properties instead of the whole row.